# Evaluating a complex definite integral of $e^{-st^{2}+it}$ from t=0 to t= infinity maybe gamma function??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What would be the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st^{2}+it}dt$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit. I have tried long and hard , tried to use gamma function, substitution , converting to double integral but couldn't find the solution. Does the solution even exist in closed form. If it exists , please help in finding it..

Comment: Try completing the square on $-st^2+it$.

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi }
   e^{\left.-\frac{1}{4}\right/s} \left(1+i
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{s}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{s}},\Re(s)>0\right]$$

Comment: Sorry , I didn't get you.. how would I do completing the square here?? @dxdydz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes the Gaussian integral by performing a suitable substitution.
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st^{2}+it}dt
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(t^{2}-\frac{i}st)}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s((t-\frac{i}{2s})^2+\frac1{4s^2})}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-\frac{i}{2s})^2-\frac1{4s}}dt\\
&=e^{-\frac1{4s}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-\frac{i}{2s})^2}dt\\
\end{align}$$
Then applying the substitution $u=\sqrt{s}(t-\frac{i}{2s})\implies du=\sqrt{s}dt$ gives
$$\begin{align}
e^{-\frac1{4s}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-\frac{i}{2s})^2}dt
&=\frac{1}{e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\int_{-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}du\\
&=\frac{1}{e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\int_{-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}}^0 e^{-u^2}du+\frac{1}{e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du\\
&=\frac{i\sqrt{\pi}}{2e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\mathrm{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2e^{\frac1{4s}}\sqrt{s}}\left(1+i\mathrm{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Which result have you used sir while obtaining the limits of second substitution and subsequently breaking the integration into 2 part?

Comment: I only applied one substitution, so you'll have to explain which part. To split the integral I just used that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^b f(x)dx$ for all $c$.

Comment: I meant $u$ varies from $\frac{-i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ to $\infty-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ then how does it break into $\frac{-i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ to $0+$other term?? Shouldn't $\frac{-i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ stay throughout the integral?? @Peter Foreman

Comment: I never wrote $\infty-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ I just wrote $\infty$ because $\mathrm{erf}(\infty + a)=\mathrm{erf}(\infty)$ for all $a$

Comment: At first it is an integral whose input is along a line parallel to the real axis at a distance of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}$ below it . Then you transformed it into an integral whose input is along the imaginary axis from $\frac{-i}{2\sqrt{s}}$ to $0$ + an integral whose input is along real axis from $0$ to $\infty$ . Which result enables you to do so? Do you get my point now??

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\mathrm{erf}(x)+c$ hence the integral $\int_a^b e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(\mathrm{erf}(b)-\mathrm{erf}(a)\right)$. So the integral is given by $\int_{-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}}^{\infty-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}} e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(\mathrm{erf}(\infty-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}})-\mathrm{erf}(-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}})\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(1+i\mathrm{erfi}(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}})\right)$

Comment: Thank you,now i understand :)

Comment: It is due to conjure integration